# No Network Access After Motherboard BIOS Update

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet

On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, networking (ethernet) was working fine until I updated my ASRock B550M Pro4 motherboard's BIOS to the latest version. Now, whenever I boot into Ubuntu, there is no longer any access to the network.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

It also appears that my ethernet interface is disabled.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

 *-network DISABLED
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

**No `ifconfig`**

Unable to install `ifconfig` because there is no internet access

**No `NetworkManager.state`**

Tried a few commands below, but they dont work:

```
$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager
cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager: No such file or directory
```

and no output from running:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

**Restarting networking service doesnt help**

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

**3 network interfaces found**

`ip a` shows 3 interfaces

- `lo`
- `enp4so`
- `docker0`

**Output of `ip r`**

```
$ ip r
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

**Output of `ip a`**

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4so: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 15500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:64:4b:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NOCARRIER,BROADAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
```

**Ethernet is enabled in BIOS**

In the BIOS settings, `Onboard LAN` is `Enabled`.

**Internet access in Live Session**

Able to ping google.com and ping 8.8.8.8

**`dkms` and `netplan`**

`dksm` not installed, and cannot be installed without network access.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp7so:
      dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Any suggestions on how to recover network access? Thanks!

Comment: To enable ethernet in BIOS ?

Comment: This ^^^ That should be the first thing to check. More often than not UEFI or BIOS updates reset some settings.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Just checked in the BIOS settings that `Onboard LAN` is `Enabled`

Comment: Use a live session and check if it is working then. If not your issue is hardware related and not a problem with Ubuntu.

Comment: Full optput of `ip a` and `ip r` will be useful. `enp4s0` looks as normal ethernet interface.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dkms status`.

Comment: @Rinzwind In the live session, it is able to ping google.com and ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: @heynnema Updated question with the outputs. Looks like `enp7so` shows up in netplan yaml, but `ip a` shows `enp4so`.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Updated the question with these outputs.

Comment: @heynnema Edited that yaml file, replacing `enp7s0` and `enp4so` and rebooted the system. And it is now able to access the internet! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, after editing the netplan yaml file, I tried running `netplan generate; netplan apply` but network access was not restored until after a reboot. Is there another command to run so that we can avoid a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your /etc/netplan/*.yaml...

Change this...

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp7so:
      dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

To this...

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4so:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`